# My Dataframe is a combination of numeric and string values. df.median() method is showing me error.How can I find median of numeric values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN0Wg.png)

input:df.median()

output: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py:786, in nanmedian(values, axis, skipna, mask)
785 try:
--> 786     values = values.astype("f8")
787 except ValueError as err:
788     # e.g. "could not convert string to float: 'a'"

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'I am a developer by profession'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[128], line 1
----> 1 df.median()

input:df.median()

expected:
CompTotal        62000.0
ConvertedComp    57287.0
WorkWeekHrs         40.0
CodeRevHrs           4.0
Age                 29.0
dtype: float64

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can always convert your column [to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) and coerce strings to `nan`

Using a minimum dataframe:

```
# INIT
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
choices = [100,102, "zxfa"]
rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col':rng.choice(choices, 10)})
```

df2 print:

```
    col
0   100
1  zxfa
2   102
3   102
4   102
5  zxfa
6   100
7  zxfa
8   100
9   100
```

First convert using `to_numeric` and then calculate median with `skip_na=True`

```
pd.to_numeric(df2['col'], errors='coerce').median(skipna=True)
```

Output:

```
100.0
```